# Find the Maximum and Minimum Values of $f(x) = \cos\sqrt{x+1} - \cos\sqrt{x}$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I saw today in a fb forum the following excersice:

Find the range of values of 
$f(x)=\cos\sqrt{x+1}-\cos\sqrt{x}$

I have tried to find the mix and max of the function but failed. Any ideas?

Comment: what's domain?.

Comment: @mathworker21 I would assume $x \ge 0$

Comment: Obviously $D_f=[0,+\infty)$

Comment: A sketch might suggest the minimum is when $x=0$ and the maximum perhaps $x \approx \left(\frac32 \pi\right)^2-1/2 \approx 21.7$ though it turns out the maximum is in fact about when $x\approx 19.69588764$.  That makes the minimum $f(0) =\cos(1)-1 \approx -0.4596977$ and the maximum about $0.10856$ rather than the roughly $0.106$ the sketch might have suggested

Comment: Wolfy says $[-0.459698, 0.108561]$, where $-0.459698 \approx -\cos\left(\frac{9(\pi - 8)}{40}\right)$.

Comment: Please don’t forget that the series for $\cos\sqrt x$ makes sense beyond $x=0$, and for negative $x$, you get $\cosh\sqrt{-x}$.

Answer (score 5):

To do an analytic check of the range, and possibly other properties, note you can combine the $2 \cos$ terms into a multiple of one $\sin$ term using several identities from [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). First, note that $\cos(\theta) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$, so you get

$$f(x) = \cos\sqrt{x+1}-\cos\sqrt{x} = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \sqrt{x+1}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \sqrt{x}\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Next, you can use the [Arbitrary phase shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Arbitrary_phase_shift) formula for a linear sum of $2$ $\sin$ values which gives

$$a\sin y+b\sin(y+\theta )=c\sin(y+\varphi ) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

where

$$c={\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab\cos \theta }} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

and

$$\varphi =\operatorname {atan2} \left(b\,\sin \theta ,a+b\cos \theta \right) \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

where $\operatorname {atan2}$ is the principal arc-tangent angle in $(-\pi,\pi]$ (more details are at [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2))). For the case of \eqref{eq1}, you have $a = 1$, $b = -1$, $y = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sqrt{x+1}$ and $\theta = \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$. As such, \eqref{eq3} gives

$$c = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos\left(\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}\right)} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Since $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$ is a strictly decreasing function, from $1$ towards $0$, for $x \ge 0$ and $\cos$ is also a decreasing function in $(0,1]$, this means that at $x = 0$ you have $c = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos(1)}$ is it's maximum and, since $\cos(0) = 1$, its infimum is $0$ since $c \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

You can do similar appropriate checks for the range of $\varphi$ values in \eqref{eq4} and then determine, overall, the range of possible values for \eqref{eq1}.